# How To Create Multiple Attribute In Magento For Product Details Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to create multiple attribute in magento for product details page because i have to show two things on the product details page and they are attribute first of all i have color swatches with the help of attribute i am showing on the product details page the next thing is the google map and each different product has a different google map how to show two attribute in magento product details page any help would be very appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first create an attribute. Read [here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html) on a simple tutorial on how to do that.

To display any product attribute in magento you need the "Attribute Code". Lets say you make a attribute called "Gogole Map" with a Attribute Code "gmap". You would need to open the html for the product detail page which can be found

```
app/design/frontend/default/[your template]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and just add the following code to where you want to place

```
<?php echo $_product_getGmap();?>
```